# Are there billing or performance implications of multiple listeners vs single parent

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

If i structure my firebase realtime database node like this:

```
{
    vehicles: {
        '-vehicle-one-id': {...details },
        '-vehicle-two-id': {...details },
        ...
    }
}
```

Is there any good performance or billing reasons between watching the whole bucket vs watching each vehicle individually.

Eg.

```
db.child('vehicles').on("value", someDispatcher)
```

vs

```
['-vehicle-one-id', '-vehicle-two-id, ...].forEach(id => 
    db.child('vehicles').child(id).on("value", someDispatcher)
)
```

Firebase documentation indicates that a user can't watch .child('vehicles') if any node underneath is not accessible based on rules therefore the need for more granular listeners.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a significant difference between the two.  There are only performance issues if you make poor decisions in your listeners.